# varnish in front of php-fpm laravel

Tags: varnish

My deployment looks like this:

```
                                          /->php-fpm (Laravel)
Client->Nginx(HTTPS)->Varnish->Nginx(HTTP)
                                          \->static files
```

So I have an inner Nginx instance that deals with sending the request to php-fpm or serving the static files.

Can I eliminate this inner Nginx and if so how can I configure Varnish to send the request to php-fpm or directly serve the static files?

Comment: Do you need Varnish at all? nginx can do its own caching, and if your needs aren't too complex it ought to work. Then you have only a single nginx instance, instead of two nginx plus varnish.

Comment: I wanted to use varnish because it gives me a way to programmatically flush the cache for particular routes from my application

Comment: Consider https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge